# Turning this simple block to idiomatic Python code

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, idioms

```
def run(first, second):
    sum=[]
    for i in range(len(first)):
        third.append(second[i]+first[i])
    return sum

print run([1,2,3],[10,20,30])
```

The code works fine and prints out a list with three elements where each element is the sum of the two elements of the same index in "second" and "first", specifically `[11, 22, 33]`. Is there a more straightforward approach to return the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use the [`zip()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

```
def run(first, second):
    return [a + b for a, b in zip(first, second)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def run(first, second):
...     return [a + b for a, b in zip(first, second)]
... 
>>> print run([1,2,3],[10,20,30])
[11, 22, 33]
```

Answer (score 2):

And just to point out another way, which circumvents zip, but does introduce map... (and some find less readable or don't like...)

```
from operator import add
third = map(add, first, second)
```

Comment: Notice that in Python > 3 this won't do what you think it does... Instead of `third` being a list, it will be a generator instead. You'll need to wrap the RHS in `list()` in order to obtain a real list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in functions [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> map(sum, zip([1, 2, 3], [10, 20,30]))
[11, 22, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option as posted by Martijn:

```
def run(a, b):
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

One possible improvement is to make it work with arbitrary number of lists, not just two:

```
def run(*args):
    return [sum(p) for p in zip(*args)]
```

Another generalization is to allow other operators:

```
def run(func, *args):
    return map(func, *args)
```

and then, for example:

```
import operator

print run(operator.add, [1,2,3],[10,20,30])  # [11, 22, 33]
print run(operator.sub, [1,2,3],[10,20,30])  # [-9, -18, -27]
```

Note that in all three cases, the `run` as a separate function is not necessary and can be simply replaced with a built-in call.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `map` - although it's interesting to to note the difference between `zip` and `map` when handling different list lengths.

I think in most situations @Marijn Pieters `zip` solution would do what you want because `zip` is more cuddly and soft in it's handling of lists.

```
In [414]: first = [1,2,3]
In [415]: second = [10,20,30]
In [416]: [a + b for a, b in zip(first, second)]
Out[416]: [11, 22, 33]

In [417]: import operator
In [418]: map(operator.add, first, second)
Out[418]: [11, 22, 33]

In [419]: second = [10,20,30,40]
In [420]: [a + b for a, b in zip(first, second)]
Out[420]: [11, 22, 33]

In [421]: map(operator.add, first, second)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-421-dd15f26f1e89> in <module>()
----> 1 map(operator.add, first, second)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

In [422]: map(None, first, second)
Out[422]: [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (None, 40)]
```